# Swift 2.0 and objective-c compatibility method returns Bool with parameter NSError

Tags: objective-c, swift, error-handling, compatibility, nserror

I am working on a new project that uses objective-c frameworks, and all the new code is in `Swift`. I have come across an interesting issue with compatibility. The problem comes with Swift 2.0 where any method in `objective-c` that returns a `BOOL` and takes a `NSError` parameter is translated into a method that returns `Void` and `throws` in `Swift`. An example of this translation would be `NSManagedObjectContext` save method which is now in Swift:

```
public func save() throws
```

This is  not a problem when the code is called from Swift and the implementation is also in Swift.

The problem I am facing is with frameworks that I can't (or should not) modify in objective-c that follow the same pattern. In this case I am implementing that method which is defined in an `objective-c` protocol, when implementing it in `Swift`, the only way to make the compiler happy, is to return Void and throw something, when `objective-c` calls my method, it catches the error internally and the return value becomes `NO`, which is the behavior I want.

However now the `NSError` that would tell me what happened is nil, and there appears to be no way to set it from Swift, since it is not even passed in the parameter, and the only way to comply with the protocol is by taking it out. Not only do I not see the message in my throwed exception, but also now I see no `NSError`. I only know the call failed but don't have any message to log/display of why it failed, or to perhaps retry under certain failure conditions.

I was looking for a way that Objective-c could bridge a `ErrorType` to `NSError` but can't find anything at all. Just in the same way it internally catches the `ErrorType` and sets the return value to NO.

Is there a way this can be solved, *without changing the objective-c protocol definition?.*

Comment: Is the protocol defined in Swift or Objective-C, and what does it look like? Is the implementation in Swift or Objective-C? – Finally, can't you just throw an `NSError(...)` from Swift?

Comment: @MartinR The protocol is defined in Objective-C, the method looks something like - (BOOL)myMethod(some params.... NSError *__autoreleasing *error). The implementation is in Swift, I can throw an NSError but the objective-c code calling the protocol implementation will just catch the error and set the return value to NO, I need a way to see that NSError in the objective-c code, the framework uses it to report the error.

Comment: I cannot modify (at this time) the existing objective-c code where the protocol is defined and where the protocol method (which is implemented in Swift) is called from objective-c.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem, perhaps I am misunderstanding it. – If the Swift function throws `throw NSError(domain: "domain", code: 1234, userInfo: ["foo" : "bar"])` and is called from Objective-C as `[obj myMethod:... error:&error];` then `error` is set to that thrown NSError. – A self-contained reproducible example would be helpful!

Comment: @MartinR I made a mistake, it actually works correctly if I throw an NSError, thank you!. feel free to post the answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given a protocol definition

```
@protocol MyProtocol <NSObject>
- (BOOL)myMethod:(NSInteger)x error:(NSError *__autoreleasing *)error;
@end
```

you can implement a conforming class in Swift and throw an `NSError`:

```
class SwClass : NSObject, MyProtocol {

    func myMethod(x: Int) throws {
        if x < 0 {
            throw NSError(domain: "my.domain", code: 1234, userInfo: ["error" : "called with negative argument"])
        }
    }
}
```

When called from Objective-C, the error is assigned to the passed
`NSError` variable:

```
-(void)foo {
    SwClass *obj = [[SwClass alloc] init];
    NSError *error;
    if (![obj myMethod:-3 error:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"%@", error);
    }
}
```

It does therefore not matter if the protocol method is implemented
in Objective-C or in Swift.